Global minimum of exponential distributed data fitted to Nakagami-m distribution?
I tried finding a minimum such that  $$
D_{KL}\left(f_\mathrm{E}\lvert\lvert f_\mathrm{N} \right) =
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} a\mathrm{e}^{-ax}\ln \left(\frac{a\mathrm{e}^{-ax}}{\frac{2}{\Gamma(m)}\left(\frac{m}{\nu}\right)^m x^{2m-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{mx^2}{\nu}}}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x,
$$
solved to
$$
\ln \left(\frac{a\Gamma(m)}{2}\left(\frac{\nu}{m}\right)^{m}\right)-1+\left(2m-1\right)\left(\gamma+\ln a\right)+\frac{2m}{\nu a^2}
$$
is minimal.
I then derived
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} D_{KL}\left(f_\mathrm{E}\lvert\lvert f_\mathrm{N} \right)= \frac{2 m \left(a^2 \nu - 2\right)}{a^3 \nu} =0,
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \nu} D_{KL}\left(f_\mathrm{E}\lvert\lvert f_\mathrm{N} \right)= \frac{m \left(a^2 \nu - 2\right)}{a^2 \nu^2} =0,
$$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial m} D_{KL}\left(f_\mathrm{E}\lvert\lvert f_\mathrm{N} \right)=\frac{2}{a^2\nu} + 2 \ln a + \ln\left(\frac{\nu}{m}\right) + \psi(m) + 2 \gamma - 1,
$$
found $a^2=\frac{2}{\nu}$ and solved the last expression to
$$
\ln\frac{2}{m}+\psi(m)+2\gamma = 0,
$$
but even with all this effort, I can't express $m$ satisfyingly, numerically it is $\approx 0.36$.
The Nakagami distribution is defined with $x> 0 \quad m \ge \frac{1}{2}\quad \text{and}\quad \nu> 0 $ in Wikipedia, Matlab allows values below (there $\mu =m$ and $\omega=\nu$). The second expression is now only depended on $m$ as
$$
g(m)=\ln \left(\frac{2^m\Gamma(m)}{2m^m}\right) +\left(2m-1\right)\gamma +m-1,
$$
with
$g(0.36)\approx 0.028$.
Forcing $m=\frac{1}{2}$ results in
$$
\ln\frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}}+\psi(\frac{1}{2})+2\gamma = \gamma,
$$
and $g(0.5) \approx 0.0752$.  The Nakagami distribution reduces to the half-normal with $m=\frac{1}{2}$, the result is the same, as if a half-normal was used instead. Now $g(m)$ is increasing for $m\geq\frac{1}{2}$. I think $m\approx 0.36$ is the global minimum. If I take data from an exponential distribution and fit it to a Nakagami distribution in Matlab $m$ will be stuck at this value. So what is happening here? Should I switch to a half normal distribution for this case in Matlab or is it allowed to let $m$ fall below its bound?

The professor took a look and pointed out that the of the integral of the probability density functions needs to be one and all moments need to exist for the specific $m$. Then one would have a function that does everything required. I then tried to solve
$$
\int\limits_{0}^\infty \frac{2}{\Gamma(m)}\left(\frac{m}{\nu}\right)^m x^{2m-1}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{mx^2}{\nu}}\, \mathrm{d}x \overset{!}{=} 1 ,
$$
for all the $m$. I found
$$
\frac{2 \Gamma(m)}{2 \Gamma(m)} \left(\frac{m}{\nu}\right)^m\left(\frac{\nu}{m}\right)^m \frac{\nu}{m} \frac{m}{\nu} = 1,
$$
so I think at the very least $m>0$ is fine.
What becomes more concerning then is $x>0$ or $x\geq0$, here again depending on the source one can find both. The former seems to be sensible if $m<\frac{1}{2}$ is allowed. The argument for the previous integral to be solvable for $x>0$ and $m<\frac{1}{2}$ can be made by use of the incomplete gamma functions
$$
\int\limits_{s}^\infty x^{n-1} \mathrm{e}^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \Gamma\left(n,s\right),
$$
and then taking the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow0} \Gamma\left(n,s\right) = \Gamma(n).
$$
So for integration it doesn't matter, all moments exist, the global minimum exist and all is fine. Maybe this is helpful to someone else.
